# How to find highest column value every month but display date in date column

Tags: sql, cursor

I have a table in SQL. I want to find total column with highest data every month using cursors. If I use `MONTH(currentDate)`, I get month in date column. But I want date in that column and group by month.

Comment: First, you don't need cursors for this.  Second, edit your question and add sample data and desired results.  The question is not particularly clear and doesn't explain the data format or what results you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have all dates and also `Month` and `Total of Month` use below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MONTH([Date]) As [Month],
        SUM(Value) As [Total],
        MAX(Value) As [Maxim]
    FROM 
        yourTable
    GROUP BY 
        MONTH([Date])) DT ON DT.[Month] = MONTH(yourTable.[Date])
```

Comment: but if we give SELECT MONTH(DATE) only month will be displayed in the column.My requirement is to display date in the column but group by month to get highest value of that month.

Comment: @Kavya :p, Please check the results, As I write in answer, by this type of query you will have a `Date` column and also `Month` column and a `Total` column and I add a `Max` column ;).